# Pandas group data by customized time window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with DateTime and I want to plot the aggregated number of data points every 3 weeks.

What can I do to have pandas group by my data in a customized fashion, like 3 weeks or 3 days?

I know you can use grouper to have the data grouped on a monthly basis or weekly basis.

The data is shown below.

```
 {'date': {0: '12/31/20',
  1: '12/31/20',
  2: '12/31/20',
  3: '12/30/20',
  4: '12/30/20',
  5: '12/30/20',
  6: '12/30/20',
  7: '12/30/20',
  8: '12/30/20',
  9: '12/30/20',
  10: '12/30/20',
  11: '12/30/20',
  12: '12/29/20',
  13: '12/29/20',
  14: '12/29/20',
  15: '12/29/20',
  16: '12/29/20',
  17: '12/28/20',
  18: '12/27/20',
  19: '12/26/20',
  20: '12/25/20',
  21: '12/25/20',
  22: '12/23/20',
  23: '12/23/20',
  24: '12/23/20',
  25: '12/23/20',
  26: '12/23/20',
  27: '12/23/20',
  28: '12/23/20',
  29: '12/22/20',
  30: '12/22/20',
  31: '12/22/20',
  32: '12/22/20',
  33: '12/22/20',
  34: '12/21/20',
  35: '12/21/20',
  36: '12/21/20',
  37: '12/21/20',
  38: '12/20/20',
  39: '12/18/20',
  40: '12/18/20',
  41: '12/18/20',
  42: '12/17/20',
  43: '12/17/20',
  44: '12/17/20',
  45: '12/17/20',
  46: '12/17/20',
  47: '12/16/20',
  48: '12/16/20',
  49: '12/16/20',
  50: '12/16/20',
  51: '12/16/20',
  52: '12/16/20',
  53: '12/15/20',
  54: '12/15/20',
  55: '12/15/20',
  56: '12/15/20',
  57: '12/15/20',
  58: '12/15/20',
  59: '12/15/20',
  60: '12/15/20',
  61: '12/14/20',
  62: '12/14/20',
  63: '12/14/20',
  64: '12/14/20',
  65: '12/14/20',
  66: '12/14/20',
  67: '12/14/20',
  68: '12/14/20',
  69: '12/13/20',
  70: '12/13/20',
  71: '12/12/20',
  72: '12/12/20',
  73: '12/12/20',
  74: '12/12/20',
  75: '12/11/20',
  76: '12/11/20',
  77: '12/11/20',
  78: '12/11/20',
  79: '12/11/20',
  80: '12/11/20',
  81: '12/11/20',
  82: '12/11/20',
  83: '12/10/20',
  84: '12/10/20',
  85: '12/10/20',
  86: '12/10/20',
  87: '12/10/20',
  88: '12/9/20',
  89: '12/9/20',
  90: '12/9/20',
  91: '12/9/20',
  92: '12/8/20',
  93: '12/8/20',
  94: '12/8/20',
  95: '12/8/20',
  96: '12/8/20',
  97: '12/8/20',
  98: '12/7/20',
  99: '12/7/20',
  100: '12/7/20',
  101: '12/7/20',
  102: '12/7/20',
  103: '12/7/20',
  104: '12/7/20',
  105: '12/6/20',
  106: '12/6/20',
  107: '12/5/20',
  108: '12/5/20',
  109: '12/5/20',
  110: '12/4/20',
  111: '12/4/20',
  112: '12/4/20',
  113: '12/4/20',
  114: '12/4/20',
  115: '12/4/20',
  116: '12/4/20',
  117: '12/4/20',
  118: '12/4/20',
  119: '12/4/20',
  120: '12/4/20',
  121: '12/3/20',
  122: '12/3/20',
  123: '12/3/20',
  124: '12/3/20',
  125: '12/3/20',
  126: '12/3/20',
  127: '12/2/20',
  128: '12/2/20',
  129: '12/1/20',
  130: '12/1/20',
  131: '12/1/20',
  132: '11/30/20',
  133: '11/29/20',
  134: '11/29/20',
  135: '11/26/20',
  136: '11/25/20',
  137: '11/24/20',
  138: '11/23/20',
  139: '11/21/20',
  140: '11/20/20',
  141: '11/19/20',
  142: '11/19/20',
  143: '11/19/20',
  144: '11/17/20',
  145: '11/17/20',
  146: '11/17/20',
  147: '11/17/20',
  148: '11/16/20',
  149: '11/16/20',
  150: '11/15/20',
  151: '11/15/20',
  152: '11/14/20',
  153: '11/13/20',
  154: '11/9/20',
  155: '11/8/20',
  156: '11/7/20',
  157: '11/5/20',
  158: '11/5/20',
  159: '11/4/20',
  160: '10/28/20',
  161: '10/28/20',
  162: '10/28/20',
  163: '10/28/20',
  164: '10/28/20',
  165: '10/27/20',
  166: '10/27/20',
  167: '10/27/20'
}}
```

Comment: You can use `pd.Grouper` with frequencies like 3 days or 3 weeks, e.g. `pd.Grouper(key='dt', freq='3D')` for 3 days

Comment: @perl Thanks, it works. Although it acts in a weird way like the first day was on Wednesday and it was grouped in a time window starts from three weeks before the first day in my dataset. The origin parameter didn't work.

Comment: Based on what I see in the documentation, it should be the `offset` parameter, not the `origin` (haven't tried it though, so no guarantee :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
df_sampled = df.set_index('date').resample('3M').mean().reset_index()
```

In the example, the aggregation is mean. Replace with your aggregation function. You do require an additiobal column with the values you want to aggregate of course.

After these steps, you may plot with df.plot() or use matplotlib or some other library